# Parent div overlapping Child div

Tags: css, webforms

The table created within a child div is overlapped by the parent div.  I have a custom.css for overriding the boostrap stylesheet.  What .css is missing?

[image: td cell]

[image: table stylesheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the box grey box (authorized users) must have `overflow: hidden;`

Try applying it this:

```
.yourClass{
    overflow: visible;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was focusing on the table, when I should have been looking into the outer divs.